# Tensorflow get_variable into Pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, pytorch

I am trying to convert this TensorFlow code into PyTorch. For example, I converted the below TF code

```
tf.get_variable("char_embeddings", [len(data.char_dict), data.char_embedding_size]),  char_index)  # [num_sentences, max_sentence_length, max_word_length, emb]
```

into

```
class CharEmbeddings(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config, data):
          ....
          self.embeddings = nn.init.xavier_uniform_(torch.empty(len(data.char_dict), data.char_embedding_size))


    def forward(self, char_index):
        # [num_sentences, max_sentence_length, max_word_length, emb]
        char_emb = self.embeddings[char_index]
```

I don't understand 100% what TF is doing there. Is it supposed to first initialize `char_embeddings`, gather (which I understand) and then backprogate gradients to update the `char_embeddings` value so that in the next iteration, the `char_embeddings` will be updated?

If so, I tried to convert that into PyTorch and from what I read, if no initializer is passed to the `get_variable` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/get_variable), the `glorot_uniform_initializer` will be used which is I think it equivalent to pytorch `xavier_uniform_`

Two questions here:

1. Is my interpretation of TF code correct?
2. Is that conversion valid?
3. Should I expect the original embeddings `self.embeddings` to backpropagate and update its values? Is that the expected behavior from the tensorflow version as well? and how to achieve that in Pytorch? I added `requires_grad` to the embeddings tensor but that doesn't update the values.

Those might be newbie's question but I am new to this. Thanks!